# Generic function to set field of different structs used as map values

Tags: dictionary, go, generics, interface

Having structures with common fields...

```
type Definition struct {
        Id string
        ...
}
type Requirement struct {
        Id string
        ...
}
type Campaign struct {
        Id string
        ...
}
```

...I have multiple functions like this:

```
func fillDefinitionIds(values *map[string]Definition) {           
        for key, value:=range *values { // Repeated code
                value.Id=key            // Repeated code
                (*values)[key]=value    // Repeated code
        }                               // Repeated code
}
func fillRequirementIds(values *map[string]Requirement) {           
        for key, value:=range *values { // Repeated code
                value.Id=key            // Repeated code
                (*values)[key]=value    // Repeated code
        }                               // Repeated code
}
func fillCampaignIds(values *map[string]Campaign) {           
        for key, value:=range *values { // Repeated code
                value.Id=key            // Repeated code
                (*values)[key]=value    // Repeated code
        }                               // Repeated code
}
```

I would like to have a single function, generalizing the access with generics (or interfaces, whatever), kind of...

```
func fillIds[T Definition|Requirement|Campaign](values *map[string]T) {           
        for key, value:=range *values {
                value.Id=key
                (*values)[key]=value
        }                                
}
```

Of course, this gives `value.Id undefined (type T has no field or method Id)`. I've been able many times to overcome similar issues, but this time I can't find a solution for this.

How can be this set of functions be abstracted as a single one?

Comment: Have the three types implement an "id setter" interface, and use the interface as the type parameter.

Comment: @mkopriva  (they are not just three) While I can implement a setter for each type (which just moves the repeated code to other locations), it seems to me the `(*value)` reference would also need to be generic. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/k0tIiRMh0uB Yes setting of the id is repeated, but the loop is not. Go generics do not yet support "generic struct field access", so you *need* a method that will read/write the field. You can avoid repeating the method by **embedding** a common type containing common fields.

Comment: Note also that you do not need `*map` for what you're doing in the example code. `map` already has an internal pointer to the hash table. https://go.dev/play/p/F3Qk0gcyKEa

Comment: @mkopriva After testing, I see your solution is the most elegant and precise. Can you post it as an answer, please?

Comment: The answer's been added now, Rodolfo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```golang
type Definition struct {
    Id string
}
type Requirement struct {
    Id string
}
type Campaign struct {
    Id string
}

func (v Definition) WithId(id string) Definition   { v.Id = id; return v }
func (v Requirement) WithId(id string) Requirement { v.Id = id; return v }
func (v Campaign) WithId(id string) Campaign       { v.Id = id; return v }
```

```golang
type WithId[T any] interface {
    WithId(id string) T
}

func fillIds[T WithId[T]](values map[string]T) {
    for key, value := range values {
        values[key] = value.WithId(key)
    }
}
```

```golang
func main() {
    m1 := map[string]Definition{"foo": {}, "bar": {}}
    fillIds(m1)
    fmt.Println(m1)

    m2 := map[string]Campaign{"abc": {}, "def": {}}
    fillIds(m2)
    fmt.Println(m2)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/F3Qk0gcyKEa

---

An alternative to @blackgreen's answer if using a map of *values* is a requirement.

```golang
type Common struct {
    Id string
}

func (v *Common) SetId(id string) { v.Id = id }

type Definition struct {
    Common
}
type Requirement struct {
    Common
}
type Campaign struct {
    Common
}
```

```golang
type IdSetter[T any] interface {
    *T
    SetId(id string)
}

func fillIds[T any, U IdSetter[T]](values map[string]T) {
    for key, value := range values {
        U(&value).SetId(key)
        values[key] = value
    }
}
```

```golang
func main() {
    m1 := map[string]Definition{"foo": {}, "bar": {}}
    fillIds(m1)
    fmt.Println(m1)

    m2 := map[string]Campaign{"abc": {}, "def": {}}
    fillIds(m2)
    fmt.Println(m2)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/AG050b0peFw

Comment: in the second snippet, optionally, `T` can be constrained to a union to ensure a restricted type set, instead of `any`. Signature: `func fillIds[T Definition | Requirement | Campaign, U IdSetter[T]](values map[string]T)`

Answer (score 8):

Compose your structs with a struct that includes the common field(s), and define a setter method on that common type:

```
type Base struct {
    Id string
}

func (b *Base) SetId(id string) {
    b.Id = id
}

type Definition struct {
    Base
}
type Requirement struct {
    Base
}
type Campaign struct {
    Base
}
```

Then define the interface constraint as a union of pointer types, *and specify the setter method*. You must do this, because generics field access isn't available in the current version of Go.

```
type IDer interface {
    *Definition | *Requirement | *Campaign
    SetId(id string)
}

func fillIds[T IDer](values map[string]T) {
    for key, value := range values {
        value.SetId(key)
        values[key] = value
    }
}
```

Example: https://go.dev/play/p/fJhyhazyeyc

```
func main() {
    m1 := map[string]*Definition{"foo": {}, "bar": {}}
    fillIds(m1)
    for _, v := range m1 {
        fmt.Println("m1", v.Id) 
        // foo
        // bar
    }

    m2 := map[string]*Campaign{"abc": {}, "def": {}}
    fillIds(m2)
    for _, v := range m2 {
        fmt.Println("m2", v.Id)
        // abc
        // def
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of generics in `fillIds` is rather moot, though. Define an interface with the `SetID` method, and using the function `func fillIDs(vals map[string]IDer)` is all it takes

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem generics is useful is you want to restrict the admissible types. Other than that, yeah, interfaces work just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't really think a function like `fillIds` should be made to care about what types it operates on. Its job is to call 1 method on whatever types it is compatible with. Anything that implements an interface is compatible, and will work. The base type provides the interface, so you don't have to maintain the constraint, etc... keeping it simple. I'm perhaps a bit too pedantic about this. I like using generics when they make sense, IMO it's just one of those features that is often over-used, producing code-smell

Comment: *generics field access isn't available in the current version of Go.* And I hope it never is!

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, not using generics requires the caller to convert the map first, though.

Comment: @Peter: that's true. That said, looking at the question I did find myself wondering how one would end up with a map with ID's as keys, and values being different objects that didn't have those ID's set already. Decided to try and be a bit more constructive than just commenting saying that this looks like an X-Y problem to me :)

Comment: Cool. What I was missing was the trick `type x interface { *A_POINTER!!! | ... }`. +1, peace, out.

Answer (score 3):

Generics are for cases where the same code works for any number of types, like:

```
func Ptr[T any](v T) *T {
    return &v
}
```

You're wanting to use generics to actually *modify* specific fields in a number of different types, then generics aren't really the way to go. That's essentially not what they're intended to be used for, and golang already has features that allow you to do just that: Composition and interfaces.

You have identified shared fields, great, so create a type and embed it where needed:

```
type Common struct {
    ID    string
}

type Foo struct {
    Common
    FooSpecificField  int64
}

type Bar struct {
    Common
    BarOnly    string
}
```

Now add a setter on the common type:

```
func (c *Common) SetID(id string) {
    c.ID = id
}
```

Now all types that embed `Common` have an `ID` field, and an setter to go  with it:

```
f := Foo{}
f.SetID("fooID")
fmt.Println(f.ID) // fooID
b := Bar{}
b.SetID("barID")
fmt.Println(b.ID) // barID
```

To accept a map of all types that allow you to set an ID, all you really need to do is make `fillIds` accept the required interface:

```
type IDs interface {
    SetID(string)
}

func fillIDs(vals map[string]IDs) map[string]IDs {
    for k, v := range vals {
        v.SetID(k)
        vals[k] = v
    }
    return vals
}
```

Because setters should, by definition, be pointer receivers, you could probably write the same function even shorter:

```
func fillIDs(vals map[string]IDs) map[string]IDs {
    for k := range vals {
        vals[k].SetID(k)
    }
    return vals
}
```

Using interfaces indicates that this function wants to interact with the objects you pass to it, through a known/defined interface. Using generics indicates that you're expected to provide data that will be used as a whole. Setting fields is not using data as a whole, hence I'd argue generics aren't the right tool for the job. Generics *can* be very powerful, and extremely useful in certain cases. A while back, I [posted a review on code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/275391/suggestions-for-improvement-for-generic-array-and-map-functions-in-go-1-18/276128#276128) about generics to create a concurrent-safe map. That's an excellent use-case for generics, so much so that I ended up implementing such a type in response and put it up on [github](https://github.com/EVODelavega/smap)

I thought I'd mention this that I don't oppose generics at all. They can be very useful. The thing I object to is the over-use of the feature, which can -and often does- lead to code that is smelly, and harder to read/maintain.

Comment: "actually modify specific fields in a number of different types, then generics aren't really the way to go"... I understand _access to generics fields isn't available in the current version of Go_ , but not that generics should not _generalize_ access (or that generics should not generalize contents modification). Can you explain, please?

Comment: @RodolfoAP: I phrased it a bit broad, perhaps. In simple terms, I'd say it boils down to: interfaces abstract the types from the logic that will modify the state/data, whereas generics abstract the data/state away from the logic. In my example, the `Ptr` function logic is applied equally, regardless of type/state/data. The interface to set the ID, however, ensure that the data allows for the logic to operate on the data by calling `SetID` with a known type. It's a subtle, yet IMO significant difference

Comment: Got it, thanks. But this does still not work https://go.dev/play/p/Za7c3qWIOuf I'm forced to use `map[string]Foo`, coming from an external lib, how to generalize this?

Comment: @RodolfoAP As mentioned elsewhere, you'll have to construct the map to have a variable of type `map[key]interfaceType`. `map[string]Foo` is just that: `map[string]Foo`