# Generics: constraints and struct embedded in interface

Tags: go, struct, interface, composition

The following code does not compile, and reports `./main.go:35:7: Test does not satisfy Constraint (Test missing in main.StructWithName)`

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Test struct {
    Name string
}

func (t Test) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Name: %v", t.Name)
}

type StructWithName struct {
    Name string
}

type Constraint interface {
    StructWithName
    // ~struct {
    //  Name string
    // }
    String() string
}

func Print[T Constraint](x T) {
    //s := T{}
    fmt.Printf("Hello %v", x)
}

func main() {
    t := Test{
        Name: "Test",
    }

    Print(t)
}
```

However, if I comment out the `StructWithName` and uncomment the ~struct block, then it compiles fine. I can't wrap my hear around the semantic difference between both.

What I was trying to do was to have a generic method that could handle structs in a generic way; i.e. `x := S{}` then pass it along to an external library. In this case, it's for a Terraform provider, the code in the resources are very similar and I'm a bit troubled by the amount of repetition I see in exiting providers; in my case resources are extremely similar, some just have one or two fields on top of the default structure). I was hoping to be able to write a set of generic methods to do all that is similar and only specificities somewhere else (duh!).

I'm still early in my go journey and I can't make sense of the compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually want, if I understood you correctly, is not possible. Go generics do not support access to struct field subsets.

- See related: [Generic function to set field of different structs used as map values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74770559/generic-function-to-set-field-of-different-structs-used-as-map-values/74771033#74771033)

---

As far as the error in question is concerned...

The name of a type specifies the type's identity and two types with different names (which are not aliases of each other) are always *distinct*, so `Test` and `StructWithName` are two distinct types. The only thing they have in common is their *underlying type*.

The `type Constraint interface { StructWithName }` interface is a type set that contains only one type, namely `StructWithName`, and since `Test` is not a member of that type set this means that it's impossible to satisfy that constraint with the type `Test`.

Type `struct { Name string }` is an unnamed type, the underlying type of any unnamed type is the type itself, i.e. the underlying type of `struct { Name string }` *is* `struct { Name string }`.

The tilde in front of a type in a constraint, i.e. `~T`, means *any* type with *underlying type* identical to `T`. Or, more precisely,

> The type set of a term of the form ~T is the set of all types whose underlying type is T.

So when you do

```
type Constraint interface { ~struct { Name string } }
```

then the constraint's type set will contain any type that has `struct { Name string }` as its underlying type.

Comment: Thanks, that's more or less what I figured out in the meantime, but now it's clearer :-)